Bulk-removing self-overlapping polygons
Using QGIS 3.18, I ran the topology checker on a polygon layer (gpkg format). It found several thousands self-intersections.
I can see the errors, but I cannot seem to be able to delete the polygons ?
I can't manually fix thousands of polygons.
Do you know how I could delete the faulty polygons ?

Must not overlap (itself). For additional info, I've tried v.clean but it crashes (due to the overlaps I presume).  Check validity (core QGIS plugin) will say geometries are valid. Cleaning geometries/adding a 0,01 m buffer does not fix. I can provide a sample, but I cannot guarantee that the sample will feature the errors.

Yes. It does not remove any error.

Yes, this is expected. Those are overlapping, but they are not self-overlapping. What I have is self-overlapping polygons, i.e polygons that intersect with themselves

Can you add a screenshot showing the rule settings you use? I cant find Must not overlap (itself)
